# Javascript array deep copy not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two javascript arrays. I need to copy the array values from one another. I have used code like below.

javascript

```js
let firstArr = [{name: "one"},{name: "two"}];
let secondArr = [...firstArr];
secondArr[0].name = "three";
console.log(firstArr)
console.log(secondArr)
```

I have changed only "secondArr" values. But first array values are also changed. I have used the spread operator, so it will create a new memory then why the first array values are also changed?

Could you please anyone explain this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[...` only creates a shallow copy

Comment: If you look at MDN, you'll see this: *Note: Spread syntax effectively goes one level deep while copying an array. Therefore, it may be unsuitable for copying multidimensional arrays.*

Comment: use - `lodash.js`

var firstArr = [{name: "one"},{name: "two"}];
var secondArr = _.cloneDeep([...firstArr]);
secondArr[0].name = "three";
console.log(firstArr)
console.log(secondArr)

Comment: Use `array.map()` method.